# Regular expression for pdf file URL

Tags: regex, url, pdf

I'm looking for a regular expression for a url of this format:

- www.website.com/sample.pdf
- http://www.website.com/sample.pdf
- https://www.website.com/sample.pdf

Comment: What do you want to do exactly : capture it ? validate it ? and what language are you using ?

Comment: I want to validate it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use this general pattern:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?www\.([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})\/[\w \.-]+?\.pdf$
```

[`DEMO`](https://regex101.com/r/eI7rC5/1)

Or, if you want to validate that EXACT url, then you can use:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?www\.website\.com\/sample\.pdf$
```

[`DEMO`](https://regex101.com/r/eI7rC5/2)

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                      the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                      group and capture to \1 (optional
                         (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    http                 'http'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    s?                   's' (optional (matching the most amount
                         possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                    ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                   '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \/                   '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                     end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                         quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                         repetition of the captured pattern will be
                         stored in \1)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  www                    'www'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                     '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  website                'website'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                     '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  com                    'com'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \/                     '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  sample                 'sample'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                     '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  pdf                    'pdf'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                      before an optional \n, and the end of the
                         string
```

**Java code:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String input = "https://www.website.com/sample.pdf";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(https?:\\/\\/)?www\\.website\\.com\\/sample\\.pdf$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Match found");
} else {
    System.out.println("NO Match found");
}
```

Comment: You got a Java for android version?

Comment: @Bouss it should work for JAVA too, simply use double slashes `\\ ` whenever a simple slash is used

Comment: It's not working with the double slashes, could you show me the java version? Thanks

Comment: @Bouss Example added